Rebase and Deployment in GH Actions
I have a deployment.yml workflow in my repository that looks like this:
name: Run deploy

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - staging
      - dev

Nothing fancy, has some steps to set the environment based on the branch name, build some images... the usual stuff.
In my team, we avoid merge commits and we like to have a linear change history. For that purpose, we use rebasing. So that PR's to develop are always rebase and merged through Github UI
Due to the fact that how Github treats rebases (changing the hash) when GIT CLI does not, using the rebase and merge option it's not feasible when promoting changes from develop to staging, as you will end up with N commits ahead and behind develop, whit the same code after merging.
So that we usually checkout staging, pull from develop using rebase, and then push, so that now the history is clean and matches both enviroments.
However, due to the fact that how GH action event triggering works, each time we do this, now the deployment workflow starts running in both branches (staging, dev), and of course has some weird behaviors, like inheriting the status of the job from the previous run instead of actually running it, and more weird stuff.
The desired behavior would be to run the workflows only in the targeted branch. So for example if we have to do some pre-release, after pushing changes to staging, the workflow should only run in staging, without triggering any other workflow that has already run at any time in the past
I guess this is a issue a lot of people have faced and solved, just wondering how your solutions are
Ideally, the solution would not involve having several workflows for several branches, as in the example there is only a deployment workflow, but there would be lots of other jobs like testing, automatic semver etc
Thanks a lot!
